# Using html text as selector for CSS with JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm sure others have asked this but I just cant' find anything that helps me.

Have a look at [this code on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SDxt8/1/).

Both Person1 and Person2 have

```
class="from"
```

And the CSS selector is .from so it applies to both but I'm trying to achieve that it only applies to Person1 with JavaScript/jQuery.

I've tried numerous things such as

```
$( "span.from:contains('Person1')" )
```

with no success. How should I do this?

Help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: In jQuery or just CSS? How about `$('.from:eq(0)')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$( "span.from:contains('Person1')")` works just fine. But in css you are still affecting all elements with `.from` class. After you get the element with Javascript, you should do something with it, like add a new class, and change the css so that the animation runs only on the new class.

```
$( "span.from:contains('Person1')").addClass('newClass')
```

CSS:

```
.newClass{
    -webkit-animation: color-change 1s infinite;
    ...
}
```

Comment: `$("span.from:contains('Person1')")` is the OP's original solution which he said didn't work, but it does. It's what he does after he gets the element is what's relevant.

Comment: You should be able to just the nth child selector here, without JavaScript. `.from:nth-of-type(1) { /* styles here */ }`

Comment: True, it works in this specific case. But I think the OP was going for a more dynamic solution. Otherwise he could've just added some class to every `span` containing 'Person1', and define the animation there.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can use **[`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter)**

```
$("span.from").filter(function(){ return this.innerHTML == "Person1"; })
```

to remove the animation of the item remove the from class using **[`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass)**

```
$("span.from").filter(function(){ 
     return this.innerHTML == "Person1"; 
}).removeClass('from');
```

Comment: Do you use a new JS syntax?

Comment: @ComFreek : oh I'm really sorry for that

Comment: Could you demonstrate it in my jsfiddle? I'm not really the best at this and it's not working out for me

Comment: I probably haven't explained it good enough but without the CSS Person1 and Person2 are red, with the CSS they're flashing different colours and I'm trying to achieve that only Person1 flashes and Person2 is just red.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can work

```
$("span.from:contains('Person1')").text()
```

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9G3sb/) fiddle

Comment: Yes but Person2 still uses the css in your fiddle and I'm trying to make it so only Person1 does

Comment: You mean that Person2 does not have a 'from' class?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using straight up CSS you should be able to select just the first item using the nth-child selector:

```
.from:nth-of-type(1) { /* styles here */ }
```

If you wanted to select the first item via JS you would simply need to use eq() to grab the first item by index. This is chainable, so you could continue to set set CSS on this item similar to this (so in this example I'm adding an extra class on the first .from, and also setting its background color):

```
$(".from").eq(0).addClass("first-item").css("backgroundColor", "orange");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try with `.not()`

```
$(".from:not(span:contains('Person2')):eq(0)")
```

Comment: won't this return all elements except the span with person2?

Comment: yeah it will...to prevent that we can use '.eq()' like '$(".from:not(span:contains('Person2')):eq(0)")'